# Nested Array Search in Mongo db using regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

what would be query for searching in nested arrays:

```
"_id" : "123",
"Array1" : [
    {
        "field1" : {
            "nestedArray1" : [
                {
                    "content" : "This string inside %nestedArray%",
                }
            ]

        },


    }
],
```

I have tried using the following regex
Array1.field1.nestedArray1.content

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.append("Array1.field1.nestedArray1.content", new Document("$regex", ".*" + "%nestedArray%" + ".*"));
```

But i am not able to get the proper results..Is the above query in right format

Comment: So what is not the "proper results"? What do you receive and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: i meant  i have a record which is not being fetched with the above query..

Comment: Works for me. I suggest a typo or unexpected input in real code. My guess here is that you are actually trying to "build" the regex string in the query. But this is not what your question is showing.

Comment: @NeilLunn..Thanks..actually am using mongo db java driver..so  i was building the regex string in the query

Comment: Understand then that your "question" does not include a "variable" but instead just includes a regular "string". This of course matches and works just as expected. Therefore "Unclear what you are asking", "cannot reproduce your error" and various other reasons no-one can help you unless you can provide a case we **can** reproduce. Which we presently cannot. It's up to **you** to provide that case, and presently you have not. Again, I suggest you look carefully at actual input and expression building, as your real logic ( which is not here ) will be what is at fault.

Comment: @NeilLunn..as you told there is some problem on my end while expression building..the below command worked from mongo command line ..Thanks a lot.. db.campaignDetails.find({"Array1.field1.nestedArray1.content" :{"$regex":"%nestedArray%"}}) and is working as expected..